# Select and insert OR insert and ignore error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has one unique column. I will insert records into it using PHP.

If there is a record with this unique column, do not insert, Else, insert.

Should I first select and decide whether insert or not.

Or

Insert anyway and ignore duplicate errors?

Which one more efficient？

Comment: check `on duplicate key`, you coult use it in insert query so no select or error ignoring needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `INSERT INGORE` syntax.. you shoud not be worry about checking the data before inserting.

Quoted from [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> INSERT IGNORE in the treatment of new rows that contain unique key
>   values that duplicate old rows: The new rows are used to replace the
>   old rows rather than being discarded